# How to find and click on a hidden button with selenium?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

I am trying to use a selenium python script to try to click on a button which is only visible when the mouse hovers over a certain region of the webpage. The code I use so far is as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.swisscom.ch/de/privatkunden/mobile/devices.html")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']")
hrefs = element.find_elements_by_class_name('primary-button')
print(len(hrefs))
```

which seems to work, but returns `0` entries in `hrefs`. But in the inspector of firefox I clearly can see this element within the element of the given `id`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to find that button element and be able to click it?

P.S. I am not able to use the record ability of selenium ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929844/how-to-use-xpath-of-button-in-selenium-rc)) because the button becomes only visible when the mouse is hovered above a certain element, as shown here:

[image]

Addendum:

Given the 'help' I change a line in the script to:

```
hrefs = element.hover().find_elements_by_class_name('primary-button').click()
```

which gives an error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'hover'
```

Addendum on the help by Andersson: I change part of the code as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hover.perform()
hrefs = hover.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='primary-button']")
```

but got an error

```
AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_xpath'
```

If I use the following line of code instead:

```
hrefs = element.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='primary-button']")
```

I get 9 elements, although I expecte only one single "Bestellen"-button element (see images in the question).

Comment: Any reason you have created a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412437/how-to-click-on-a-hidden-button-in-selenium)?

Comment: Then why not [edit] the old question instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Because I was not sure the error I discovered might solve my problem entirely. And instead of having people to read and understand a question which is not a valiud one any more, I decided to delete this question. Better delete a question first and avoid having people waste their times, than to let people read the question and later to realize what they have read is completely out of date. But to be honest - I really would appreciate an answer to THIS question than to have a pointless discussion on when or why or how to delete or edit a question...

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34207238/selenium-xpath-hidden-by-js/34208133#34208133 or here http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: Then the procedure you should have followed is to delete the question, edit it to make it correct, then undelete. I'm pointing this out to help you, it's certainly not pointless and comments like that will not make anyone want to assist.

Comment: @fabersky: I am not sure your suggestions have something to do with my problem. I have no experience with jQuery and wonder why I need this...

Comment: Oh I can undelete a question? I did not know!

Comment: Will do it next time...

Comment: @Alex the only thing you need in here is to chain the two events. Do a hover over and then click. Use the conditional statements.

Comment: @Alex See, this wasn't pointless :)

Comment: @a_bhi_9: Could you give a concrete example code? I do not understand what you are talking about. Hover where? The `element`?`And then click where?

Comment: Why can't I just select the element 'primary-button' within the given id, and click there? what is the problem?

Comment: What you can do is use this method described here, https://gist.github.com/ab9-er/d0e058301e2616f10a3d and as for your callback, create a function that would check if the selector element `is_displayed` if not then `mouse_over` and pass this function as a callback here.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Please provide an example code!

Comment: What does this mean: "create a function that would check if the selector element is_displayed if not then mouse_over"? How to do that?

Comment: You should use `driver.common.action_chains.ActionChains()` method to simulate mouse navigation to required object and then clicking on button

Comment: I tried your sugestion as good as I understand it, and updated the question. It did not work. I guess I am doing something wrong, but not sure what it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried with two different approaches

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print driver
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://www.swisscom.ch/de/privatkunden/mobile/devices.html")
```

Directly finding elements with class_name = 'primary-button'

```
hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('primary-button')
print hrefs
print(len(hrefs))
```

Result:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe390d0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe39290>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe39250>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe391d0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe394d0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ed10>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ecd0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ec50>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ec10>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ec90>]
10
```

On div element find all buttons using xpath

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']")
hrefs = element.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='primary-button']")
print hrefs
print len(hrefs)
```

Result:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ee10>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ee50>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ee90>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4eed0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ef10>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ef50>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4ef90>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe4efd0>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0xe58050>]
9
```

And your approach:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']")
hrefs = element.find_elements_by_class_name('primary-button')
print hrefs
print len(hrefs)
```

Result:

```
[]
0
```

On the other hand finding elements by xpath can be relative to other elements
. From the docs:

> You can use XPath to either locate the element in absolute terms (not
>   advised), or relative to an element that does have an id or name
>   attribute.

So the second approach gives you list of required elements

**Update**:

The real problem is that the target element is not visible until you hover on the parent div.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.swisscom.ch/de/privatkunden/mobile/devices.html")

div_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'gridProduct10247118')))
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(div_element)
hover.perform()

button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='gridProduct10247118']//a[@class='primary-button']")))
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button)
hover.perform()

button.click()
```

Comment: But I do not understand. I expect to have exactly one (1) primary button element given a `gridProduct` id (corresponding to the selected phone). Why would I get nine (9) buttons? There is only one single button labelled "Bestellen" I want to click on. How to do that?

Comment: For every phone item on that page there is "Bestellen" button with class name 'primary-button'

Comment: every button points to a different location i.e., `href` attribute is different. So if know on what item you want to click use partial_link_text match. [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-hyperlinks-by-link-text )

Comment: I want to click on that "Bestellen" button that is inside the html div element that begins with `<div id="gridProduct10247118" ...` just as  shown in the first image in my question

Comment: I want to click on a single button, not on nine buttons. And I do not know the link-text at this might change. I just want to click on the button that is shown in the image in the question, regardless of where the link leads to!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98694/discussion-between-alex-and-termi).